# Solid tori decomposition of a lens space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have the following definition of a lens space $L:=L(p,q)$:

Given two positive integers $p,q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1, q<p$, define a $\Bbb Z_p$ action on $S^3$ as $j (z,w) :=(\zeta^j z, \zeta^qj w)$, where $\zeta=e^{2 \pi i /p}$. The resulting quotient space $S^3/\Bbb Z_p$ is called a lens space, denoted $L(p,q)$.

1. What I want to show is that $L$ can be decomposed into two solid tori, i.e.
   $$ L \approx S^1 \times D^2 \cup _{\varphi_{p,q}} D^2 \times S^1$$
   , where $\varphi_{p,q}$ is a gluing map of the boundary tori. How do I have to do this?
2. Also, I want to use the above decomposition to compute the homology groups of $L$. To this end, let $A$ and $B$ be open neighborhoods of the two solid tori, so that $A$ and $B$ are homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, and $A \cap B$ is homotopy equivalent to a torus. Then we may use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $L=A \cup B$. Since we know the homology groups of $A, B$ and $A \cap B$, we can easily compute the homology groups of $L$ except $H_1(L)$ and $H_2(L)$. Indeed we have

$$ H_2(A) \oplus H_2(B)=0 \to H_2(L) \to H_1(T^2)=\Bbb Z^2 \to H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B)=\Bbb Z^2 \to H_1(L) \to \tilde{H_0}(T^2)=0 $$

So we need to examine the map $H_1(T^2) \to H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B)$. To do this, I think I should know the map $\varphi_{p,q}$ above. Am I right?

Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For 1 you can take the tori corresponding to $|z|\leq 1/2$ and $|w|\leq 1/2.$ Then you just need to work out the maps for the Meyer-Vietoris sequence.

Comment: See [Hatcher's 3-Manifolds Notes](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mfds.pdf), starting in the middle of page 39.